# Linking xo65 object files with ELF objects and LLVM IR files

Tags: linker, llvm, 6502

I have a bunch of LLVM IR / BC files that, at the moment, I am compiling to native code with LTO using `clang`:

```
llvm-mos/bin/clang 
  --config llvm-mos-sdk/build/commodore/64.cfg \
  -O2 \
  -o _build/chip8.prg  \
  _build/dir.c.ll  \
  _build/interrupt.c.ll \
  _build/main.c.ll  \
  _build/dir.s.o  \
  _build/panic.ll.bc \
  rs/target/release/deps/chip8_engine-2a1bf4bc9333b677.bc \
  rs/target/release/deps/chip8_c64-a95cc9a5a3e99697.bc
```

Here, I am consuming three kinds of input files:

- The `.ll` files are LLVM IR files
- The `.bc` files are LLVM BC files
- The `.o` file is an ELF file (`file` reports it as `ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, *unknown arch 0x1966* version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`)

This works, but now I would like to add some xo65 object files compiled with CC65 to the mix. I can't just add them to the `clang` invocation, because that fails on `ld.lld` guessing the file's meaning wrong:

```
ld.lld: error: _build/native/readdir.c.o:30: unclosed quote
```

So my question is, **what are my options for linking together these files?** The obvious solution would be to just compile `readdir.c` using `clang`, foregoing CC65 (and thus the xo65 object file format); unfortunately, that is easier said than done, because `readdir.c` imports a whole load of low-level platform-specific imports that are written in an assembly syntax that isn't compatible with LLVM's assembler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [a relevant feature request ticket](https://github.com/llvm-mos/llvm-mos/issues/29) in the LLVM-MOS issue tracker. As of 2021-09-13, the answer to this question is in the negative: this is an open problem with no implemented solution.

Answer (score 1):

xo65 files are not in ELF format.  As of this writing, they cannot be linked directly with llvm-mos ELF format files.  This isn't impossible in principle; support for it has not been created on either side of the equation yet.